# Adding numbering to Drupal 7 menu items

Tags: drupal, menu, numbers, overriding

I would like to overide the drupal 7 menu output to display numbering before each menu item. So each menu would have a number before it in numerical order, starting at 1.

Im currently using this function to overide the output:

```
function FDP_link($variables) {
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '><sup>01</sup>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>
';
}
```

The problem is I need the number to be dynamic, ie increase by 1 with each menu item. Can someone please help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static array inside your function to increment the value each time it is called:

```
function FDP_link($variables) {
  static $counters;
  $counters[$variables['element']['#theme']]++;
  return '<a href="' . 
         check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' .
         drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . 
         '><sup>'.sprintf('%01d',$counters[$variables['element']['#theme']]).'</sup>' .
        ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</a>
';
}
```

Or you may also find a way to intercept the menu items with a preprocess_block() hook.

Comment: Thanks demental, this did the trick, just had to change the "sprintf('%01d'" to "sprintf('0%d'" to show the 0 properly.